# How to convert any type of Number into BigDecimal without toString()?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm using now this method, to execute addition on any type of `Number`:

```
public <T extends Number> CustomNumber add(T a, T b) {
    BigDecimal numberA = new BigDecimal(b.toString());
    BigDecimal numberB = new BigDecimal(a.toString());
    return new CustomNumber<>(numberA.add(numberB));
}
```

I'm using BigDecimal, because as far as I know this is the best solution, to execute precize calculations. How can I change this method, to achieve the same result without the `toString()` method? `CustomNumber` is the class I'm using to store numeric values.

Comment: What's the problem with using `toString()`?

Comment: You shouldn't..

Comment: Use `valueOf(<number type>)` static method.

Comment: Java _really, really_ won't let you try to generalize over `Number` types like this.  Give up and pick one `Number` type to use throughout your program.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't risk it, particularly if you want to construct a `BigDecimal` from a floating point type.

In the most general case, construction from a `String` is the safest way. Always take the requisite amount of care with locale-dependent decimal separators.